# Payment Gateway adding language url (Wordpress/Polylang/Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have a Wordpress Website running Woocommerce. The website is available in 3 different languages. I Run the Polylang Plugin. I have a payment Gateway called Europabank. When i order a product and select this gateway everything works perfectly. I can pay the given amount and the payment is succesful. But after the payment the user gets redirected to the website confirmation page. The plugin handles this with the following code:

```
'feedbackurl' => WC ()->api_request_url ( 'WC_Gateway_EuropabankMpi' ),
'redirecturl' => WC ()->api_request_url ( 'WC_Gateway_EuropabankMpi' ),
```

After the payment the url will look like this:

> http://my-website-url.com/wc-api/WC_Gateway_EuropabankMpi/?somedata

This url will give a 404 error because the language is not provided, when i change the url into: (added **/en/**)

> http://my-website-url.com/en/wc-api/WC_Gateway_EuropabankMpi/?somedata

will work. So i need to add the language code to the url. Which i can do with:

```
<?php  $currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
                switch ($currentlang) {
                case "nl-NL":
                echo "/nl/";
                break;
                case "fr-FR":
                echo '/fr/';
                break;
                case "en-GB":
                echo '/en/';
                break;
                default: echo '/en/';
        };?>
```

**Question**

Where do i have to add this code? I don't mind changing the Plugin directly cause it will not need to be updated, but if you have a update proof solution that would be obviously better.

**Plugin Versions & links**

- Wordpress : Version 4.4.1
- Woocommerce: Version 2.4.12
- [Polylang](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) : Version 1.7.12
- [Europabank MPI](https://www.europabank.be/ecommerce-professioneel) : Version 1.0

Comment: `plugins > woocommerce > woocommerce.php` **Line : 410** Try modifying that function and I think you will get your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you **Rophil_PHPBeginner** for pointing out the correct place to put it.

Working code in woocommerce.php :

```
    $currentlang = get_bloginfo('language');
            switch ($currentlang) {
            case "nl-NL":
            $lang = "/nl";
            break;
            case "fr-FR":
            $lang = '/fr';
            break;
            case "en-GB":
            $lang = '/en';
            break;
            default: $lang = '/en';
    };

    if ( strstr( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ), '/index.php/' ) ) {
        $api_request_url = trailingslashit( home_url( $lang . '/index.php/wc-api/' . $request, $scheme ) );
    } elseif ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
        $api_request_url = trailingslashit( home_url( $lang . '/wc-api/' . $request, $scheme ) );
    } else {
        $api_request_url = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', $request, trailingslashit( home_url( '', $scheme ) ) );
    }

    return esc_url_raw( $api_request_url );
}
```

**UPDATE**

Woocommerce has now provided a filter to solve this issue
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/56d303f4d3139336d539514f9dc15efda0a0381c

Comment: You can post [woocommerce](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce) to provide `filter` so that it can be changed without altering core. You can post that question as reference.

Comment: i cant understand how to use  woocommerce_api_request_url filter